# Problems in Mythbuntu 12/HDHomerun Prime setup

Tags: linux, setup, mythtv, mythbuntu

**Introduction**
I am newbie when it comes to PVR setup. I have messed around with tvheadend in openelec, but since it seems unable to handle an HDHomerun Prime with a cable card from Comcast (It only recognizes one mux for a sino KQED channel and I am unable to get it to do anything more), I have decided to switch to MythTV.

**Project**
1) Develop a mythtv backend server in a VM with a user-friendly web interface for scheduling recordings and viewing a TV guide
2) Add USB cameras to Raspberry Pis on the network and sent video feeds to MythTV for a home CCTV system
3) Move VM to ESXi host machine
4) Configure XBMC and Android clients for remote and local access

**My Setup**
-My MythTV "hardware": VMwarePlayer 6 with 1GB ram and a 60GB virtual HDD
-My HDHomerun Hardware: HDHomerun Prime with 20130328 firmware (Project:Connect) and Motorola CableCard
-My Software: Fresh Mythbuntu 12 install.

**Problems**
Problem 1: HDHomerun Config programs don't detect any tuners on the network (I can detect them on my Windows machine, so it is not a network problem). Do I need to install the dvb drivers in mythbuntu? What am I doing wrong?

Problem 2: I need to find a comprehensive setup guide for someone who is dealing with a cablecard setup (preferably for people unfamiliar with PVR). Every time I have tried to follow a series of online guides, there is a problem (ie: part of a guide setting up mysql server, then a subsequent guide for mythtv backend which does something incompatible with the first guide)

**UPDATE:**
If I type the following in the terminal, I get this:

> user@mythbuntu-12:~$ hdhomerun_config 13177E7A get /sys/model
>   unable to connect to device

However, if I substitute the IP address for the ID, I get this (channel is currently tuned via UPnP announced video stream to an XBMC Gotham build):

> user@mythbuntu-12:~$ hdhomerun_config 192.168.1.200 get /sys/model
>   hdhomerun3_cablecard
>   user@mythbuntu-12:~$ hdhomerun_config 192.168.1.200 get /oob/channel
>   oob2048:75250000
>   user@mythbuntu-12:~$ hdhomerun_config 192.168.1.200 get /sys/copyright
>   Copyright © 2005-2013 Silicondust USA Inc. . All rights reserved.
>   user@mythbuntu-12:~$ hdhomerun_config 192.168.1.200 get /sys/version
>   20130328
>   user@mythbuntu-12:~$ hdhomerun_config 192.168.1.200 get /tuner0/channelmap
>   us-cable
>   user@mythbuntu-12:~$ hdhomerun_config 192.168.1.200 get /tuner0/streaminfo
>   5010: 754 VELOCITY (encrypted)
>   5011: 751 APLHD (encrypted)
>   5012: 758 History HD
>   control
>   internet
>   tsid=0x2870
>   
>   user@mythbuntu-12:~$ hdhomerun_config 192.168.1.200 get /tuner0/vstatus
>   vch=758 name=History HD auth=subscribed cci=unrestricted cgms=n/a